# Regex expression to capture only numeric fields and strip $ and comma, no match if there are any alphanumeric

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group, regex-replace

I'm trying to write a regex that will strip out $ and , from a value and not match at all if there are any other non-numerics.

```
$100 -> 100
$12,203.00 -> 12203.00
12JAN2022 -> no match
```

I have gotten sort of close with this:

```
^(?:[$,]*)(([0-9.]{1,3})(?:[,.]?))+(?:[$,]*)$
```

However this doesn't properly capture the numeric value with $1 as the repeating digits are captured as like subgroup captures as you can see here https://regex101.com/r/4bOJtB/1

Comment: Do you really want to _replace and match_ with _a single regex_? Or, maybe what you want is `decimal.Parse("$12,345,678.90", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)`?

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: I did want to match, then replace with a single regex.  The decimal parse is somewhat helpful, but I was really trying to figure out if anyone knew how a nested capture group could be collected as one.  I really want to pull the results of the middle group that contains the [0-9] and non-captures the [,.], but I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named capturing group to capture all parts of the number and then concatenate them. Although, it is more straight-forward to replace all chars you do not need as a post-processing step.

Here is an example code:

```cs
var pattern = @"^\$*(?:(?<v>\d{1,3})(?:,(?<v>\d{3}))*|(?<v>\d+))(?<v>\.\d+)?$";
var tests = new[] {"$100", "$12,203.00", "12JAN2022"};
foreach (var test in tests) {
    var result = string.Concat(Regex.Match(test, pattern)?
            .Groups["v"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", test, result.Length > 0 ? result : "No match");
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/r6AFKE). Output:

```
$100 -> 100
$12,203.00 -> 12203.00
12JAN2022 -> No match
```

The regex is

```
^\$*(?:(?<v>\d{1,3})(?:,(?<v>\d{3}))*|(?<v>\d+))(?<v>\.\d+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%24*%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cv%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%28%3F%3A%2C%28%3F%3Cv%3E%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%29*%7C%28%3F%3Cv%3E%5Cd%2B%29%29%28%3F%3Cv%3E%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=%24100%0D%0A%2412%2C203.00%0D%0A%2412203.00%0D%0A12JAN2022&o=m). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\$*` - zero or more dollar symbols
- `(?:(?<v>\d{1,3})(?:,(?<v>\d{3}))*|(?<v>\d+))` - either one to three digits (captured into Group "v") and then zero or more occurrences of a comma and then three digits (captured into Group "v"), or one or more digits (captured into Group "v")
- `(?<v>\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of `.` and one or more digits (all captured into Group "v")
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is close, I was just hoping there was a way that ${v} would be everything but it is still multiple submatches v.1, v.2 etc.

Comment: @Dan You cannot capture/match(=grab into a single group value) *non-adjoining*, non-neighboring string parts. It is not how **any** regex engine works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this in single regexp, but *personal opinion here* I find dividing the problem into smaller steps a good idea - it's easier to implement and maintain/understand in the future without sacrificing time to understand the magic.

1. replace all `$` and `,` to empty string
   `[\$\,]` => ``
2. match only digits and periods as a capture group (of course you may need to align this with your requirements on allowed period locations etc.)
   `^((\d{1,3}\.?)+)$`

Hope this helps!